# How to properly use React Context Provider with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I've been going on for hours trying for stuff that I think would work but couldn't get it right. Can you help me solve this?

I have here my file browser context wherein I want to pass the folderData and call it to another function.

```
import { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

export interface fileBrowserContext {
  folderData: string;
}

export const FileBrowserContext = createContext<fileBrowserContext>({
  folderData: '',
});

export const useFileBrowserContext = () => useContext(FileBrowserContext);
```

And this is the component where I'm using it. I'm also using react-hook-form which is working when I click the submit button.

```
    const FileBrowser = () => {

      const { control, watch, handleSubmit, register, reset, errors } = useForm({
        reValidateMode: 'onChange',
        defaultValues: {
          createFolder: '',
        },
      });

      const [folderData, setFolderData] = useState<string>('');

      async function onSubmit(formData: any) {
          if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
            /* Create folder */
            setFolderData(formData.createFolder);

            reset({ createFolder: '' });
          }

          handleToastSuccess({
            message: 'Folder Created',
          });
      }


      function renderForm() {
         return (
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="CreateFolderForm">
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Create Folder</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                id="createFolder"
                name="createFolder"
                ref={register({
                  required: {
                    value: true,
                    message: 'This field is required.',
                  },
                })}
              />
            </Form.Group>

              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                type="submit"
              >
                Create
              </Button>
          </Form>
        );
      }

      const {
        isCreateFolderOpen,
        setIsCreateFolderOpen,
        handleFileCallback,
      } = useFileActionHandler(
        createFolder,
      );

      return (
        <FileBrowserContext.Provider value={{ folderData: folderData }}>
         <>
         <h1> File Browser </h1>
          {folderData + ','}
         </>
           <CustomModal
            showModal={isCreateFolderOpen}
            setShowModal={setIsCreateFolderOpen}
            modalHeading="Create Folder"
            modalContent={renderForm()}
          />
        </FileBrowserContext.Provider>
       )
    }
```

And I'm calling my useFileBrowserContext() on my utils.tsx. I need the folderData from the component above in which I'm planning to call using context to be able to save the folder in the Chonky library that I'm using.

```
export const useFileActionHandler = (
  setCurrentFolderId: (folderId: string) => void,
  createFolder: (folderName: string) => void,
) => {

  const [isCreateFolderOpen, setIsCreateFolderOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const { folderData } = useFileBrowserContext();


  const handleFileCallback = useCallback(
    (data: ChonkyFileActionData) => {
      if (data.id === ChonkyActions.CreateFolder.id) {
        // CONTEXT BEING CALLED HERE
        setIsCreateFolderOpen(true);
        if (folderData) createFolder(folderData);

      } 

      console.log('file browser', folderData);
    },
    [
      createFolder,
    ],
  );

  return {
    handleFileCallback,
    isCreateFolderOpen,
    setIsCreateFolderOpen,
  };
};
```

There is no error in my console but the behavior is that it when I console log the folderData in utils.tsx, it returns an empty string which I think means that the folderData being passed from the component is not working. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for components to use `useContext`, they must be the [descendent](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) of a `Context.Provider`. In your case, you're trying to use your `FileBrowserContext` within your `FileBrowser` component, but it's not a descendent of a `Context.Provider`, so it receives the default value for `folderData` (the empty string).

So, currently you have:

```
<App>
  <FileBrowser>
    <FileBrowserContext.Provider>
      {/* ... */}
    </FileBrowserContext.Provider>
  </FileBrowser>
</App>
```

but you need

```
<App>
  <FileBrowserContext.Provider>
    <FileBrowser>
      {/* ... */}
    </FileBrowser>
  </FileBrowserContext.Provider>
</App>
```

The fix is to move your `Context.Provider` component up a level and render it as a parent of `FileBrowser`, instead of having `FileBrowser` itself render it. You can wrap it into a custom component that handles setting the correct `value` like so:

```
const FileBrowserContextProvider = () => {
  const [folderData, setFolderData] = useState('');

  return (
    <FileBrowserContext.Provider value={{ folderData, setFolderData }}>
      {children}
    </FileBrowserContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <FileBrowserContextProvider>
      <FileBrowser /> {/* <-- now FileBrowser can safely useContext
                              since it's a descendent of the Provider */}
    </FileBrowserContextProvider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for making me understand this, It solved my problem and now I know why it was not working earlier.